# Change the Mac notification sound on a per-application basis

Tags: macos, audio, notifications

By default on Mac OS X there is a system-wide notification sound that you can choose. This sound is applied to every application and played whenever the application outputs a beep (for instance, when typing a keyboard shortcut that doesn't work, or during a terminal beep). Is there any way to change what sound this is on a per-application basis?

Specifically, I'm looking to change the sound Terminal.app uses, while every other app uses another sound.

Comment: Terminal uses the sound that is active upon its launch. If you could automate changing the sound and wrap the application launch in a script, that might be a workaround.